# Hide/reset the result every time when I clicked the button jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have these caculator code, I want to hide the result at the bottom everytime I clicked the "calculate" button on the top, how can I do that?  below is my code:

when I clicked on the calculate it should give you result of first box and all the result of the rest box, then you can still change the value from box 2 to box 4, then it will show the final result at the bottom, the issue here is when I go back to the box1 and re-input the value and calculate it, the result at the bottom remain old result, how can I hide it when I re-click the button?? full code see here: https://jsfiddle.net/jackwei/w42yocgv/248/

```js
function calculation() {
    var firstValue = document.getElementById("firstValue").value;
    var secondValue = document.getElementById("secondValue").value;
  var first1Value = document.getElementById("first1Value").value;
    var second2Value = document.getElementById("second2Value").value;
  var first3Value = document.getElementById("first3Value").value;
    var first4Value = document.getElementById("first4Value").value;
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
  var result2 = document.getElementById("result2");
  var result3 = document.getElementById("result3");
  var result4 = document.getElementById("result4");
  var resultall = document.getElementById("resultall");
    var calc =  firstValue *3 + secondValue *7 + first1Value *1 + second2Value *3;
  var calc2 =  (firstValue*1 +first1Value*1)*3 + (secondValue*1+second2Value*1)*5;
  var calc3 =  firstValue*1 + secondValue*1 + first1Value*1 + second2Value*1;
  var calc4 =  firstValue*1 + secondValue*1 + first1Value*1 + second2Value*1;;
  result.textContent = "Template Build " + calc + " Hours";
  result2.textContent =  calc2 + " Hours";
  result3.textContent =  calc3 + " Hours";
  result4.textContent =  calc4 + " Hours";
  resultall.textContent =  " Campaign Management " + calc2 + " Hours," + " Deployment " + calc3 + " Hours,"+ " Ongoing " + calc4 + " Hours";
  document.getElementById('first3Value').value=parseFloat(firstValue) + parseFloat(first1Value);
   document.getElementById('first4Value').value=parseFloat(secondValue) + parseFloat(second2Value);
   document.getElementById('first5Value').value=parseFloat(firstValue) + parseFloat(secondValue)+ parseFloat(first1Value)+ parseFloat(second2Value);
   document.getElementById('first6Value').value=parseFloat(firstValue) + parseFloat(secondValue)+ parseFloat(first1Value)+ parseFloat(second2Value);
}

  $('#first3Value,#first4Value,#first5Value,#first6Value').keyup(function(){ // run anytime the value changes
    var first3Value  = Number($('#first3Value').val());   // get value of field
    var first4Value = Number($('#first4Value').val()); 
     var first5Value = Number($('#first5Value').val());  
     var first6Value = Number($('#first6Value').val()); // convert it to a floa
    $('#result2').html(first3Value*3 + first4Value*5 + "Hours" ); // add them and output it
    $('#result3').html(first5Value*1 + "Hours");
     $('#result4').html(first6Value*1 + "Hours");
     $('#resultbox2').html(first3Value*3 + first4Value*5 + "Hours" );
     $('#resultbox3').html(first5Value*1 + "Hours" );
     $('#resultbox4').html(first6Value*1 + "Hours" );
});
```

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
#wrap{
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:8px;
    padding:5px;
  padding-bottom:15px;
    background:#fff;
    font-family:AvenirLTStd, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;    
    line-height:16px;
}
#wrap .cont_details fieldset,.cont_order fieldset{
    margin:10px;
    padding:20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#wrap legend{
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
#wrap .cont_details input{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    color:#000;
}
#wrap .input1:hover,.input1:active{
    
}
#wrap label{
    display:block;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#wrap label.inlinelabel
{
    display:inline;
}
#wrap .cont_order input{
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
#wrap .cont_order p{
    padding-top:5px;
}

#wrap input[type="radio"]
{
margin-top:8px;
margin-bottom:8px;
}

#wrap input[type="text"]:hover,
#wrap input[type="text"]:active {
background-color: #FAF398;
}

#wrap input#submit
{
margin:10px;
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:20px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
}

.totalPrice
{
    padding:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#ff0;
}

#wrap label.radiolabel
{
font-weight:normal;
 display:inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <title>Cake Form</title>
    <link href="http://files.javascript-coder.com/calculation/styles/cakeform.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="hideTotal()">
    <div id="wrap">
       
        <div>
            <div class="cont_order">
               <fieldset>
                <legend>Template Build</legend>
<label >New Template Build</label><br><input type="number"  id="firstValue" name="firstValue"  onclick="calculateTotal()" /> x Simple (3h)<br> 
              
                 <input type="number"  id="secondValue" name="secondValue" onclick="calculateTotal()" /> 
                 x Medium (7h)<br>
               
            
                <br/>
                <label >Adaptions of new templates</label>
         <br>
                            
               <input type="text"  id="first1Value" name="first1Value"  onclick="calculateTotal()" /> 
               x Simple (1h)<br> 
              
                 <input type="text"  id="second2Value" name="second2Value" onclick="calculateTotal()" /> 
                 x Medium (3h)<br/>
             
                <br/>
                <p>
                <input type="button" id="calc" onclick="calculation()" value="Calculate">

                </p>
                <div id="result" class="wrap totalPrice"> </div>
                </p>
            <div id="resultall" class="wrap totalPrice">  
              
            </div> 
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            
            <div class="cont_order">
              <fieldset>
                <legend>Campaign Management</legend>
<label >Campaign Integration</label><br>
                                 <input type="number"  id="first3Value" name="first3Value"  onclick="calculateTotal()" class="cm"> 
               x Simple (3h)<br> 
              
              
              
                <p>
                  <input type="number"  id="first4Value" name="first4Value"  onclick="calculateTotal()" class="cm"> x Medium (5h)
              
                </p>
                <div id="" class="wrap totalPrice"> Total: <span id="result2">
                </span></div>
                
              </fieldset>
            </div>
        <div class="cont_order">
              <fieldset>
                <legend>Deployment</legend>
<label >Campaign Deployment</label><br>
                                <input type="number"  id="first5Value" name="first5Value"  onclick="calculateTotal()" /> x  Per section Per Run<br> 
               
                <div id="" class="wrap totalPrice"> Total: <span id="result3">
                
              </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="cont_order">
              <fieldset>
                <legend>Ongoing</legend>
<label >
Continuous Run (non-automated) + Deployment</label><br><input type="text"  id="first6Value" name="first6Value" value="0" onclick="calculateTotal()" /> 
x Per section Per Run<br> 
               
                <div id="" class="wrap totalPrice"> Total: <span id="result4">
                
              </fieldset>
            </div>
           
                </p>
            <div id="" class="wrap totalPrice">  
              
    
            
            Campaign Management <span id="resultbox2"></span><br> Deployment <span id="resultbox3"></span><br> Ongoing <span id="resultbox4"></span><br>     </div> 
                
        </div>  
     
    </div><!--End of wrap-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi where is `calculateTotal()` and `hideTotal()` function in your code? Also , please elaborate this `I hide it when I re-click the button..` ? here you mean if user change value from first box then in last divs value should not be calculated it should calculated only when 2nd and 3rd box are click ?

Comment: should I use hideTotal() to hide it? I am new to JS, yes that's what I mean,if user change value from first box then in last divs value should not be calculated it should calculated only when 2nd , 3rd or 4rd box are click

Comment: I use calculation() combine with .keyup(function(), because 2rd result based on 1st box result, then 3,4rd base on 2rd, when 2rd 3rd or 4rd box changed, the result should change

Comment: You can simply put `$("#resultbox2,#resultbox3,#resultbox4").text("")` inside your `calculation()` function .So,whenever user click of calculate button  result in last div will be empty .

Comment: oh my god, that's works, thanks so much!!